# My basic collision detection calculation isn't working. Keeps detecting collision even when two objects are not touching

Tags: java, processing

```
Ship ship;

Asteroid[] asteroid;

Satellite satellite;

void setup() {
  size (1280, 720);
  noCursor();

  ship = new Ship(100, 50);
  asteroid = new Asteroid[3];
  for (int i = 1; i <= asteroid.length; i++) {
    asteroid[i-1] = new Asteroid(random(60, 99));
    satellite = new Satellite(random(100, 900), random(400, 700), 30);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ship.display();
  ship.move(mouseX, mouseY);
  satellite.display();
  for (int i=0; i < asteroid.length; i++) {
    asteroid[i].display();
    asteroid[i].update();
  }
  boolean collision = hitShip(ship, asteroid);
  if (collision == true);
  print("There is a hit");
}


boolean hitShip(Ship ship, Asteroid []asteroid) {

  float asteroid1 = asteroid[0].getXPos() + asteroid[0].getYPos();
  float asteroid2 = asteroid[1].getXPos() + asteroid[1].getYPos();
  float asteroid3 = asteroid[2].getXPos() + asteroid[2].getYPos();
  float shipLocation = ship.getXPos() + ship.getYPos();


  if (asteroid1 == shipLocation) {
    return true;
  }

  if (asteroid2 == shipLocation) {
    return true;
  }

  if (asteroid3 == shipLocation) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

The program involves an object 'ship' moving around the screen using the mouseX and mouseY coordinates. The goal is to prevent 'ship' from touching the asteroids, if the ship does touch an asteroid I want the console to print "There is a hit".

When I run the program the console constantly prints "There is a hit" over and over again even when the ship is not touching the asteroids.

Comment: `asteroid[0].getXPos() + asteroid[0].getYPos();` didn't you consider the fact that two objects at coordinates (0, 5) and (5, 0) are NOT in the same place but the sum would be the same?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did not consider that fact no, but many thanks for pointing that out. I am sitting here for the past hour trying to work this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `asteroid` that is at position `30,50` your code would say `asteroid = 80`

If the `ship` is at position `50,30` it is obviously not at the same position but would still be `shipLocation = 80`

To solve this you could use a `Position class` with an `equals` method:

```java
class Position {
  float x;
  float y;

  public Positon(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public boolean equals(Position position) {
    return (this.x == position.x && this.y == position.y);
  }
}
```

You can also compare every `asteroids` `x` and `y` position with the `ships` `x` and `y` positions:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < asteroid.length; i++) {
  if (ship.getXPos() == asteroid[i].getXPos() && ship.getYPos() == asteroid[i].getYPos()) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just an additional note: the coordinates are floating points, so having two objects at the very exact same position is pretty "lucky". So unless there is some rounding to Integer or some second dimension like width/height of an object, this hit detection will (theoretically) rarely trigger

Comment: @WarrenFaith I used the same thing with a snake game I created. I added everything to a grid so it can only be at specified positions